# animate ng-view for only certain pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am animating my ng-view in the same way as the example here at the moment which is in the angular docs https://plnkr.co/edit/2dcinYE8W5ZVl2PPOcBS?p=preview

I was wondering if there is a particular way to only animate the ng-view for particular links and not for others.

Then I also need to only animate the ng-view depending on if a particular link is clicked, for example: There's two links for an about page on the homepae, one in the navbar and one half way down the page. Would it be possible to only animate the view if the later link was clicked and not the link in the navbar?

```
<div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>


.view-animate {
 padding:10px;
}

 .view-animate.ng-enter, .view-animate.ng-leave {
 transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 border-left:1px solid black;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 padding:10px;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter {
 left:100%;
  }
.view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
 left:0;
 }
 .view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left:-100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the class for the animation depending on the click done by the user.

Comment: silly me! One of those moments! If anyone else needs to know I added an ng-class on the ng-view div which would be set to true if clicked on the particular link

Comment: Right. This is a possible approach